# Problems with text parsing method

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am running a thread in java during execution of infinte while loop the 2 if statements never return false.

```
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Its difficult to know whats going on in your code, because of the way the you've indented it. Consider an edit with nicer formatting. Good luck!

Comment: Catching NullPointerException is bad practice, and even more so with an empty catch block

Comment: Use equals for strings. Maybe change your formatting as it is very hard to read. USE COMMENTS IN YOUR CODE!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `equals` when comparing strings:

```
if(!jTextField5.getText().equals(s2))
```

and

```
if (!s9.equals(jTextField6.getText()))
```

The regular equality/inequality operators compare objects in memory, not string contents.